# Slicing a list in sublists according to unknown indices

Tags: python

What is the best method to slice a list (here: lst_num) into (more than two) parts of variable length according to another list containing the indices?

A string of numbers has to be split into sublists that contain the numbers standing between all subsequent occurrences of a certain number. E.g.: "30 24 17 30 22 1 67 2 4 3 30 24 95 34 29 56 30 43 24" and "30" yields: [24, 17], [22, 1, 22, 1, 67, 2, 4, 3 ]  and [24, 95, 34, 29, 56]

```
str_num="30 24 17 30 22 1 67 2 4 3 30 24 95 34 29 56 30 43 24"
lst_num=[int(x) for x in ciphtext.split()]
idx=[i for i, x in enumerate(lst_num) if x==30]
for i in idx: ???
```

To slice the list, the first argument should be "i+1", but how to obtain the subsequent index from idx as stop index? Is there a way to give each sublist a unique name in the iteration?

Comment: list slicing. keep slicing till you run out of your number.

Comment: I can't understand the pattern. You also aren't starting with 2 lists, you're starting with a single string

Answer (score 0):

One little step to go:

```
>>> [lst_num[start+1:end] for start, end in zip(idx, idx[1:])]
[[24, 17], [22, 1, 67, 2, 4, 3], [24, 95, 34, 29, 56]]
```

Just [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the indexes into pairs of slice boundaries.